# JavaScript: Can someone tell me what's going wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript

I've been doing JavaScript exercises since i haven't been doing this for too long. Got most of them working but i've been staring blind at this one.

I need to make all lowercase upper & vice versa. I checked the solution and it was helpfull but i'm sure i can get my own code ( which is very different from the answer ) working as well.

Thanks for all bits of help.

```
function swapCase (str) {
  var sen = str;
  for ( var i = 0; i < sen.length; i++) {
    if (sen.charAt(i) === sen.charAt(i).toLowerCase()) {
      sen.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
    } else if (sen.charAt(i) === sen.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
      sen.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
    }
  } return sen;
}

console.log(swapCase("UPlowUPlow"));
```

P.s: I am aware that it's not the cleanest bit of code but i've been working on it for a while. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` *return* the modified string, they don't modify it in place. So you'd have to put that value into the string you're processing, e.g.:

```
sen = sen.substring(0, i - 1) + sen.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + sen.substring(i + 1);
```

As that's fairly awkward, you'd probably be better off converting the string into an array of single-character strings, processing the array, then combining it again.

You can convert a string into an array of single character strings like this:

```
theArray = theString.split("");
```

...then process each entry, in a loop or via `Array#map`:

```
theArray[i] = theArray[i].toUpperCase();
```

...and then convert it back when done:

```
theString = theArray.join("");
```

Here's an example using `Array#map`:

```js
function swapCase (str) {
  var theArray = str.split("");
  theArray = theArray.map(function(ch) {
    var lower = ch.toLowerCase();
    return ch === lower ? ch.toUpperCase() : lower;
  });
  return theArray.join("");
}
var str = "UPlowUPlow";
snippet.log("Before: " + str);
str = swapCase(str);
snippet.log("After: " + str);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Here's the concise version:

```js
function swapCase (str) {
  return str.split("").map(function(ch) {
    var lower = ch.toLowerCase();
    return ch === lower ? ch.toUpperCase() : lower;
  }).join("");
}
var str = "UPlowUPlow";
snippet.log("Before: " + str);
str = swapCase(str);
snippet.log("After: " + str);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot! I've been straring at this code for quite a while and i've got it to work in a sec thanks to you guys.

I've made a newSen var that catches the required characters and changes the case.

I would give you all upvotes but i can't do that yet. I will return when i can do it.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`sen.charAt(i).toUpperCase()` does not change the character at the position. You need to manually update it.

```
function swapCase (str) {
  var sen = str;
  var updatedStr = "";
  for ( var i = 0; i < sen.length; i++) {
    if (sen.charAt(i) === sen.charAt(i).toLowerCase()) {
      updatedStr  += sen.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
    } else if (sen.charAt(i) === sen.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
      updatedStr  += sen.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
    }
  } 
  return updatedStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, remember that strings are immutable, [quoting](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000486/):

> In JavaScript, strings are immutable objects, which means that the
>   characters within them may not be changed and that any operations on
>   strings actually create new strings. Strings are assigned by
>   reference, not by value. In general, when an object is assigned by
>   reference, a change made to the object through one reference will be
>   visible through all other references to the object. Because strings
>   cannot be changed, however, you can have multiple references to a
>   string object and not worry that the string value will change without
>   your knowing it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the great answers, people!

Thanks to you guys, i "solved" this in seconds while i was working on it for a good amount of time.

I'd love to upvote your answers instead of writing a thank you note, but i'm not yet allowed to do that. So, i'll do it this way.